# Laravel Eloquent nested relation pivot with constraint

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, pivot-table

I am currently working with laravel 4
I am trying to retrieve collection with constraint but it doesn't work as expected

model Caracteristique :

```
public function valeur() {

    return $this->hasMany('Valeur','id_caracteristique','id');

}
```

model valeur

```
public function caracteristique() {

    return $this->belongsTo('Caracteristique','id','id_caracteristique');

}

public function produit() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Produit','produit_valeur');

}
```

model categorie

```
public function produit() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Produit','produit_categorie');
}
```

model produit

```
public function valeur() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Valeur','produit_valeur');
}
```

I want :

Caracteristique, with values where categorie = x through produit

final goal : To be able parsing collection like

caracteristique->valeur;

in SQL

```
SELECT c.id,v.id FROM caracteristique c
INNER JOIN valeur v on (v.id_caracteristique = c.id)
INNER JOIN produit_valeur pv on (pv.valeur_id = v.id)
INNER JOIN produit_categorie pc on (pc.produit_id = pv.produit_id)
GROUP by c.id
```

When i use join in eloquent relationship no longer available

I have tried this :

```
$carac = Caracteristique::with(array('valeur.produit.categorie' => function($q) {

$q->whereCategorieId(2);

 }))->get();
```

But the constraint not respected ..

Any ideas ?

Regards,

find this bad solution ...

```
$values = Valeur::whereHas('produit',function($q) {
$q->whereHas('categorie',function($q) {
    $q->where('categorie.id','=',2);

});
})->lists('id');

$carac = Caracteristique::with(array('valeur' =>function ($q) use($values) {
$q->wherein('id',$values);

}))->get();
```

Someone with best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want limit `Caracteristique`:

```
$catId = 2;

Caracteristique::whereHas('valeur', function ($q) use ($catId) {
  $q->whereHas('produit', function ($q) use ($catId) {
    $q->whereHas('categorie', function ($q) use ($catId) {
      $q->where('cateogorie.id', $catId);
    });
  });
})->get();
```

or if you want to load all `Caracteristique` and limit related `Valeur` only:

```
Caracteristique::with(['valeur' => function ($q) use ($catId) {
  $q->whereHas('produit', function ($q) use ($catId) {
    $q->whereHas('categorie', function ($q) use ($catId) {
      $q->where('cateogorie.id', $catId);
    });
  });
}])->get();
```

As you can see this is not the best piece of code to use, so instead simply use joins.

Comment: Hi, thx for reply, Very surprised That laravel does not provide best solution for nested contraint, query is awful !!

Comment: The query itself is not that awful, but the code you need to do it is. There's PR of mine to make it easier, but Taylor hasn't merged it yet https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4954

Comment: I have used laravel native relationship to build a basic, product, categories, attributes system. You think it's wrong way to do ?

Comment: Eloquent is just great for basic stuff and quick setup. However when the application requires complex logic, then I go with repository and custom methods, and finally if it needs further improvements, often replace Eloquent with Doctrine, which works a bit defferently. That being said, I wouldn't say it's wrong way, but in future you may find it not enough for yuour needs.

Comment: Ok i understood, the first query given not filtering with categorieID, returns all data of caracteristique/valeur very strange ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: the first query without with('valeur') not filltering on categorieID wherehas, returning all caracteristique with all values.